# Getting RMagick to convert images to PDF with correct formatting

Tags: image, imagemagick, pdf-generation, rmagick

I'm converting some PNG images to a multipage PDF format, and having trouble getting the size right in the PDF output.

My input is PNGs of 825 x 1125 pixels, which should be 300 dpi when sized to 2.75" x 3.75" for correct printing.  The PDF gets one image per page, and each image should be 2.75" x 3.75" in the PDF.  The sizing is the part I can't get working.  Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
require "RMagick"
include Magick

images = Dir["input_dir/*.png"]
pdf_image_list = ::Magick::ImageList.new
pdf_image_list.read(*images) 

pdf_image_list.write("output_dir/output.pdf")
```

The output PDF has each page sized to approx. 11 1/2" by 15 1/2", which is way too big.  I've tried setting the page size options (http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/info.html#page) on the PDF, like so:

```
pdf_image_list.write("output_dir/output.pdf") {
  self.page = "825x1125"
}
```

but they seem to have no effect.  Neither has any other size option I've set.